# Solving a maze by eliminating junctions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, maze

We are trying to make a program that solves any maze by recognising all junctions and eliminating the ones that do not lead to the entrance. We managed to create such a program but we are struggling to get the dots to connect to create a proper path. Does anybody have an idea how to do this because we are out of clues...[Picture of the result, but the dots aren't connect by a line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVs0k.png)

The maze is basically a  (n)x(n) grid in a numpy array with walls (true) and paths (false) see:[picture of maze as seen from the variable explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXvn9.png)

```
import numpy as np
import maze_utils as mu
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 101

maze, start = mu.make_maze(size)

start = [start[1],start[0]]

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def junctions_finder(maze, size, start):

    junctions = [start]
    end = []

    for y, row in enumerate(maze):
        for x, column in enumerate(row):

            if maze[x,y] == False:

                if x == 0 or x == (size-1) or y == 0 or y == (size-1):

                    junctions.append([y,x])
                    end.append([y,x])


                while True:

                    if x+1 < size and y+1 < size and\
                    maze[x+1,y] == False and maze[x,y+1] == False\
                    or x+1 < size and y-1 > 0 and\
                    maze[x+1,y] == False and maze[x,y-1] == False\
                    or x-1 > 0 and y-1 > 0 and\
                    maze[(x-1),y] == False and maze[x,(y-1)] == False\
                    or x-1 > 0 and y+1 < size and\
                    maze[(x-1),y] == False and maze[x,(y+1)] == False:

                        junctions.append([y,x])
                        break

                    else:

                        break

    return junctions, end

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def eliminate_coor(junctions, end, start):

    eliminated = []

    for row in junctions:

        a = row[1]
        b = row[0]

        connections = 0

        U = False
        D = False
        L = False
        R = False

        UW = False
        DW = False
        LW = False
        RW = False

        SE = False

        if row == start or row == end[0]:
            connections = 2
            SE = True

        for i in range(1,size):
            if SE == False:

                if a+i <= size-1 and DW == False and D == False:

                    if maze[a+i, b] == True:
                        DW = True

                    else:
                        for coor in junctions:
                            if [coor[1],coor[0]] == [a+i,b]:
                                connections = connections + 1
                                D = True


                if a-i >= 0 and UW == False and U == False:

                    if maze[a-i, b] == True:
                        UW = True

                    else:
                        for coor in junctions:
                            if [coor[1],coor[0]] == [a-i,b]:
                                connections = connections + 1
                                U = True


                if b+i <= size-1 and RW == False and R == False:

                    if maze[a, b+i] == True:
                        RW = True

                    else:
                        for coor in junctions:
                            if [coor[1],coor[0]] == [a,b+i]:
                                connections = connections + 1
                                R = True


                if b-i >= 0 and LW == False and L == False:

                    if maze[a, b-i] == True:
                        LW = True

                    else:
                        for coor in junctions:
                            if [coor[1],coor[0]] == [a,b-i]:
                                connections = connections + 1
                                L = True

        if connections < 2:
            eliminated.append([b,a])

    return eliminated

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def junction_remover(junctions, eliminated):

    counter = 0

    for index, row in enumerate(junctions):
        for erow in (eliminated):
            if erow == row:
                junctions[index] = -1
                counter = counter + 1

    for times in range(counter):
        junctions.remove(-1)

    return junctions, counter

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

junctions, end = junctions_finder(maze, size, start)
counter = 1

while counter > 0:

    eliminated = eliminate_coor(junctions, end, start)
    junctions, counter = junction_remover(junctions, eliminated)

start = [start[1],start[0]]     
junctions.pop(0)
pyjunc = np.array(junctions)
mu.plot_maze(maze, start=start)
plt.plot(pyjunc[:,0], pyjunc[:,1], 'o')
```

Answer (score 0):

plt.plot(pyjunc[:,0], pyjunc[:,1]) would connect the dots... Or did you mean you have a bug you can't trace? In your picture it seems there's a beginning, but no end, so it retraces back to the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.plot(pyjunc[:,0], pyjunc[:,1], 'o')
```

plots the data points in the list with the circle marker `'o'`. But you haven't defined a linestyle.

The quickest way to do this is to add it the format shorthand:

```
plt.plot(pyjunc[:,0], pyjunc[:,1], 'o-')
```

Which says to use a circle marker and a solid line `'-'`.

Expanding that out to how matplotlib interprets it, you could write:

```
plt.plot(pyjunc[:,0], pyjunc[:,1], marker='o', linestyle='-')
```

You can see the [full documentation for `plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) more ways to customise your plot